# How to do combination query parameter in fetching table records in CAKEPHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.x

on cakephp 2, I have a method to 'collect' parameter in controller, for example, at view, I have combobox A, combobox B, input 'keyword' and on controller. Then I collect that data on COntroller to create conditions filter.

then I can use it on my conditions query, like: 'conditions'=>$condition. Then somehow in CakePHP 3, the array is changed into [ ], so i can't use this method anymore.

How can I mimic that method in CakePHP 3? or is there other approach to do conditions collection?

I tried the same way as array, but it won't work. I can't find it online yet. Here the example collection i did previously

```
$conditions = array();
$conditions['StoreProduct.stok >']=0;
$conditions['StoreProduct.deleted']=0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the array is changed into []"? CakePHP 3 still accepts arrays for conditions in queries.

Comment: as i tried above, it wont receive the array i made, do you have any code example, simple one is enough to show how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommed you to use the Query Builder like:

```
$query = $articles
->find()
->select(['id', 'name'])
->where(['condition1 >' => 0, 'condition2' => 0])
->order(['created' => 'DESC']);
```

More informations: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: ic, i will look into it, but my question is to make collection of the conditions, i need to collect all filter into variable or anything i can use, then put in the query. can you show me how to collect it?

Comment: As you can see in the example, the `where` function takes an array of conditions. So, you can collect them the same as you always have.